# want to increase the size of view by dragging it by touching its corner

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

Hi,

I want to drag the subview inside my main view. After doing that i should be able to increase/decrease the size of subview by touching and dragging either of the corners or the subview.

The increase/decrease of size in each direction will depend on the corner i select for dragging.

Please suggest me ways to achieve this.